# Accessing core data on watchos3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an existing app on iOS and am now trying to add a watchOS3 app to go with this app. The problem I'm struggling with is to access my persistent store from my watch extension. I have tried to encapsulate my core data stack with my core data model into a shared framework. However, with watchOS3 (probably watchOS2 already), it is no longer possible to share the same framework between the watch app and the iOS app, as it is done in this [example](http://www.makeandbuild.com/blog/post/watchkit-with-shared-core-data).

Therefore, how can I manage to use the same core data model from my watch app and my iOS app? How can I create this shared container, Apple refers to in its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)?

Comment: have you any solution?